# Difference between "Activity" and "Activeness"

Tags: word-choice, differences

I've just seen the word "activeness" used do describe the degree of active involvement of somebody in a certain task. Should that be "activity" instead? Are both valid but there is a difference?

Comment: Info about why you're downvoting would be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess "activeness" is jargon used in a particular field, with a specialized meaning.  Or else it was written by someone whose native language has a similar word.

Comment: So "activeness" is not actually a proper english word?

Comment: Not my downvote, but when you're asking about word choice, the actual quote matters. Please post some sample text in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the *Oxofrd English Dictionary*

> **activeness**, *n*
>    The quality of being active; agility; energy, busyness.

.

> **activity**, *n*
>   1 a.  The state of being actively occupied; brisk or vigorous action; busyness, liveliness, vigour

*Activity* also has many other definitions

Neither one is marked as archaic or obsolete.

Comment: `Neither one is marked as archaic or obsolete.` - I certainly believe you on that point. But have you seen it used before? Would you use it in a sentence? It sounds odd to me, but that does not mean it's inappropriate to use it, which I think is your point.

Answer (score 1):

They are both valid, but 'activeness' is rarely used.

In fact, I do not remember ever seeing it used in any type of writing.

I consulted four dictionaries and none of them gave an example of a sentence using 'activeness'.